# asteroid result of a query

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, meteor

I am experimenting with asteroid.

My html looks like :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>

<script src="bower_components/ddp.js/src/ddp.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/q/q.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/asteroid/dist/asteroid.browser.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var ceres = new Asteroid("localhost:3000");
    var tasks = ceres.getCollection("movies");
    var _t=tasks._set
    console.dir(tasks._set._items) // line 15
    console.dir(tasks.reactiveQuery({}).result) //line 16

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The chrome console gives me this output

[image: one]

Why can't I access the result of the Query ?

Comment: Is `reactiveQuery` an async call?

Comment: Of course. That's a great point. By using setTimeout I could get the results. Thanks a lot

Comment: You should *really* be using a callback... what happens if the call takes longer than the timeout?

Comment: Yes, you are totally right. I am trying to figure out in the code how to get the callback

Comment: Looking thru the docs, looks like you want: `var query = tasks.reactiveQuery({}); query.on("change", function () { console.log(query.result) });`

Comment: Right ! Thanks a lot ! You could post that as an answer because this is exactly what i was looking for. Read the doc, but not well enough. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like `reactiveQuery` is an async call. According to the docs, you can do:

```
var query = tasks.reactiveQuery({}); 
query.on("change", function () {    
    console.log(query.result) 
});
```